# EclipseLink compilation error

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, eclipselink, resteasy

I have a maven project on NetBeans that have a Resteasy service running, this with no problem, and when I tried to add database access to use with the service using Hibernate(EclipseLink) I am getting a error:

Problem with Filer: Attempt to recreate a file for type my.package.MyClass_

I have no idea why this is happening, any tip?
Thanks in advice.

EDIT

Here is mu persstence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="br.com.meraki.curtamix_CurtamixREST_war_1PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>curtamix</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: post your persistence.xml, please

Comment: Ok, I just realized what was happening, I had a dependency (jpamodelgen) that create that class, I removed it and them the class was not created anymore. Problem solved but I still don't know why I was getting error, aw.

Comment: I need the jpa metamodel classes to be generated so removing that dependency is not option in my case. Is there a way to get rid of that filer problem using maven for building?